# How open Web AppBuilder widget programmatically?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm trying open a widget from other widget:

```
_open: function () {

    var config = WidgetManager.getInstance().appConfig.getConfigElementById("widgets_IdentifierRed_Widget");
    WidgetManager.getInstance().loadWidget(config).then(function(widget){
      WidgetManager.getInstance().openWidget(widget.id);
      console.log(widget);
    });            }
```

First I load it, then open it. But it doesn't work.

How can I open a widget from other widget?

Comment: Could you please tell 'which theme you are using???' I have read that it is also depends on the theme we are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function works for me:

```
_openPanelWidget: function (aWidgetId) {
    var def = new Deferred();
    var wm = WidgetManager.getInstance();
    var myWidget = wm.getWidgetById(aWidgetId);
    if (myWidget == null) {
      wm.appConfig.widgetPool.widgets.some(function (aWidget) {
        if (aWidget.id == aWidgetId) {
          myWidget = aWidget;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
      wm.loadWidget(myWidget).then(lang.hitch(this, function (args) {
        PanelManager.getInstance().showPanel(myWidget).then(function () {
          wm.openWidget(myWidget);
          def.resolve();
        })
      }));
    } // end if
    else {
      PanelManager.getInstance().showPanel(myWidget).then(function () {
        wm.openWidget(myWidget);
        def.resolve();
      })
    } // end else
    return def;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest as below

```
   var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
          });
          query(".jimu-widget-onscreen-icon").forEach(lang.hitch(this,function(widgetButton){
                 if(widget.name==widgetButton.dataset.widgetName){
                      widgetButton.dispatchEvent(event);
                     }
                    }));
               }),

register
```